# How to use the parent window's container in the popup window in ember application?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

In the ember.js application, there is a popup browser window, I need to use some components which have several injected services and initial ajax data.

How do I use the parent window's container to resolve the injection and the initial data, I don't want to load the data again when opening the popup.